# Brave browser: css animation doesn't work (but works in firefox)

Tags: html, css, brave

Codepen: https://codepen.io/sabeser/pen/RwYzJpd

**HTML**:

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div class='circle'></div>
    <div class='circle'></div>
</div>
```

**css**:

```css
      :root {
            --scale--ratio: 1;
        }

        #wrapper {
            background-color: yellow;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 50vh;
            width: 50vw;
        }

        .circle {
            background-color: red;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            margin: 1em;
            border-radius: 20em;
            /* set default scale */
            scale: var(--scale--ratio);
            /* enable scale animation */
            transition: scale 1.1s;
            -webkit-animation: floataround 1.1s infinite alternate;
            animation: floataround 1.1s infinite alternate;
        }

        @keyframes floataround {
            0% {
                translate: 0;
            }
            100% {
                translate: 0 -8px;
            }
        }

        .circle:hover {
            /* update scale */
            --scale--ratio: 1.2;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: green;
        }
```

In Firefox the circles move up and down and get bigger on mouse hover. In Brave they neither move nor get bigger on mouse hover.

Is there any way to make this code work in Brave browser?

Comment: I've tested on Brave and it works...

Comment: @Vi100 Which version do you have?

Comment: Can confirm, works on v1.49.132

Comment: I tried on laptop (1.36.111) and PC (1.28.106), both don't work. Mobile (1.49.132, just downloaded) works OK. I take it, my laptop and PC versions are too out of date? PS Version 1.39.122 doesn't work either. It's not great tbh, I bet many users have older browser versions. So the code won't work for them ; (

Comment: @parsecer Have you tried using a prefixer? Prefixes are in the way of disappearing but I guess older browsers still need it? Here's one of many prefiexrs you can find https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your code but with the Brave browser because some animations are not supported in this browser.
If you have noticed, there are some new css features in browsers that are implemented with -webkit-,-o-,-moz-,-ms-.
For this reason, **That should update your Brave browser with css features**.

Comment: Is there a special keyword for Brave browser, like `-mox` for Firefox?

Comment: @parsecer no
Not available for brave browser